# How to differentiate human and programatically triggered audio pause event

Tags: jquery, html, events, html5-audio, pause

So, what I am trying to achieve is that when users click on A elements, a bootstrap modal window shows up and pauses any audio that is playing. After the modal is closed, audio should be resumed.

This is the code I've been using, to no avail:

```
playingaudio = false; // global variable

$(document).on("click", "a", function(){

if (playingaudio && $('#audioplayer').length) {
  $('#audioplayer')[0].pause(); // pause audio programatically
  playingaudio = true;
}

// show modal code

});

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
// if there is an audioplayer and it is paused, resume playback
if (playingaudio && $('#audioplayer').length) {
   $('#audioplayer')[0].play();
}

});

$('#audioplayer').on('play', function() {
  playingaudio = true;
});

$('#audioplayer').on('pause', function(e) {
  playingaudio = false;
});
```

Strangely enough, this code works if I set up a breakpoint in the "playingaudio = true" line inside the A onclick event handler, but when executed without breakpoints, it fails to do what is meant to.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: maybe you should put playingaudio = false in your pause block at the top :)

Comment: Thanks for your help but doesn't seem to be the problem. I've checked and it appears that the " $('#audioplayer')[0].pause();" is executed after the following line "playingaudio = true;". I've verified this by adding alert() statements after the "playingaudio = true;" and inside the onpause() event. Maybe there is some asynchronous thing i am missing. Otherwise I can not understand what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried using `.trigger()` to differentiate user click from programmatic click?

Comment: Yes, I tried using .trigger() too. Still not working. In fact, when I use .trigger() you can see very clearly that the onpause event gets fired twice when it's triggered programmatically. I've seen that some people use the event.originalEvent property to differentiate between human and non-human clicks, for example. I tried something similar in the onpause event to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally solved it! I share the answer with you guys. Thanks for all your great help!

```
<audio controls id='audioplayer'>
<source src='http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3' type='audio/mpeg'>
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<div>
  <div>
    <span>Playing Mode: </span>
    <span class='playing_mode_label'></span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <a href="#">a button</a>
  <br>
  <button class='fake_modal'>fake modal - click to close</button>
</div>

$('.fake_modal').hide();

$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
var audioplayer = $('#audioplayer');

if (audioplayer.length) { // if there is an audioplayer
  if (!audioplayer.prop('paused') && audioplayer.prop('currentTime')) {
    audioplayer.trigger('pause'); // pause audio
    playingaudio = true;
  } else {
    playingaudio = false;
  }
}

$('.fake_modal').show(); // show modal

});

$('.fake_modal').on('click', function() {
    $('.fake_modal').hide();  //hide modal
  var audioplayer = $('#audioplayer');
    if (playingaudio && audioplayer.length) { // if there is an audioplayer
        audioplayer.trigger("play");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works as you requested.

debug: i added a central function to manage changing the variable so it can provide debug output both in the console and in a label so you can see the playing state in the html view.

mock: i don't have your audioplayer or your modal but built simple versions of them.  the modal button shows after manual pause and clicking the button simulates hiding the modal.

key changes:

1. you do need to use trigger for play and pause.  the console complained that 'play' wasn't defined.  if it was working for you, it was probably just calling the audio player method instead of your method.
2. only updating playingaudio on init and in play/pause makes it easier to not override the logic accidentally which your code was
3. the logic for restarting playback was backwards as you only want to play if it was paused.

   ```
   <div id="audioplayer">
     <div>
       <span>Playing Mode: </span>
       <span class='playing_mode_label'></span>
     </div>
     <br>
     <a href="#">a button</a>
     <br>
     <button class="play_button">play button</button>
     <br>
     <br>
     <button class='fake_modal'>fake modal - click to close</button>
   </div>


   // start out not playing
   set_playing_mode(false, "init");
   $('.fake_modal').hide();

   $(document).on("click", "a", function() {

     if (playingaudio && $('#audioplayer').length) {
       $('#audioplayer').trigger('pause'); // pause audio programatically
       $('.fake_modal').show(); // show modal
     }

   });

   // play button
   $('.play_button').on('click', function() {
     $('#audioplayer').trigger('play');
   });


   $('.fake_modal').on('click', function() {
       $('.fake_modal').hide();  //hide modal
     // if there is an audioplayer and it is paused, resume playback
     if (!playingaudio && $('#audioplayer').length) {
       $('#audioplayer').trigger('play');
     }

   });

   $('#audioplayer').on('play', function() {
     set_playing_mode(true, "play");
   });

   $('#audioplayer').on('pause', function(e) {
     set_playing_mode(false, "pause");
   });

   function set_playing_mode(mode, note) {
     playingaudio = mode;
     console.log(note + ": " + mode);
     $('.playing_mode_label').text(mode);
   }
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/azroc6sf/

Comment: Hi xeo, thanks for giving this very complete example. Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I intend to achieve. I have updated the jsfiddle to make it look more to what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/azroc6sf/1/ Using this new code as a base, what I am trying to do is that when the fakemodal is closed, playback is resumed if there was an audio playing when the modal was opened.